# A SQL query that acquires the list of categories given a page title from Wikipedia

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, categories

Given a Wikipedia page title, I'd like to acquire its categories. However, I cannot seem to find where to do this efficiently.

Here is the page table:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table

and here is the categorylinks table
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table

Where categorylinks.cl_from = page.page_id ...However, in my project, I will only have a possible page title, not the page id.  And it appears that page_title is not unique.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually talking about MediaWiki (not Wikipedia)? If yes, please, correct tags and title.

Comment: i'm talking specifically those wikipedia tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page titles are unique **per namespace**.

To search in the default namespace, search within namespace 0.  Here is the query you probably want to use:

```
SELECT `categorylinks`.`cl_to`
FROM `page`
JOIN `categorylinks` ON `categorylinks`.`cl_from` = `page`.`page_id`
WHERE `page`.`page_namespace` = 0 AND `page`.`page_title` = 'Page_name_here'
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, page_title is actually unique. It is provided by MediaWiki logics: did you try to create two pages with equal titles? How would URLs with two equally-titled pages look?

So, all you need is a query to two tables, which would get page_id from [Page table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPage_table) by title name, and use page_id in [Categorylikns table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCategorylinks_table) to get list of categories.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I originally thought, but if you look at the page table information, page_title is not listed as 'unique' or a key of any kind.  Unless that does not matter?

Comment: I think, you can rely on page_title uniqueness. I don't know any valid way to create two pages with the same titles.

Comment: I tested it out, page_title isn't treated as a unique key in the table.